# how to display inline elements in list_display?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following problem:

I have two models: Article and Comment, in Comments, i have parent = models.ForeignKey(Article). I have it set up so that Comments is inline to ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin), and CommentInline(admin.StackedInline). What i would like is that for Article list view (elements chosen in list_display), I would like to display snippets of latest comments so that the user does not have to click into each individual comments to see the changes. Now i know that i can specify a function in list_display, but i'm not sure how to do what i wish to do easily in the functions.

anyone have any suggestion on how to go about accomplishing this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, defining a function is the way to go - a custom method on the ModelAdmin class which takes the object as a parameter and returns a string representation of the latest comments:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'latest_comments')

    def latest_comments(self, obj):
        return '<br/>'.join(c.comment for c in obj.comment_set.order_by('-date')[:3])
    latest_comments.allow_tags = True
```

This takes the last three comments on each article, sorted by the 'date' field, and displays the `comment` field of each one, separated by an HTML `<br>` tag to show on one each line.