# Display admin TabularInline in list_display

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models, which are linked reverse by foreign key from my admin point of view:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128)

class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique = True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
```

And I have an admin view where I want to display the `store_id` of each product it is available in `list_display`.
I ask because I found `TabularInline` - my apporach:

```
class StoreInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Store
    readonly_fields = ['store_id', "product"]

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name",]
    inlines = [StoreInline,]
```

But how would i be able to display the `store_id` value in `list_displays` using the `Inlines` method?

--- workaround (this is only a motviation for my question above), not a solution ---

I worked around by creating a custom method but, I feel like from reading ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025679/show-children-inline-in-django-admin/54027040), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047766/how-to-display-inline-elements-in-list-display), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441755/django-admin-how-to-display-properties-defined-on-model-in-an-inline?rq=1)) that I have solved it "by hand" and not using a path Django already has. This works:

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "get_stores"]

    def get_stores(self, obj):
        return [s.store_id for s in Store.objects.filter(product = obj)]
```

Comment: Can you share what output you are getting and what you expect? because I can't understand what is actually the issue you are facing.

Comment: Simply, in the admin, when I click `Products` I get a list of all products where I want to see the `store_id` (hence the `list_display`) question. I can only achieve it with the code on the bottom of my post, but I cannot achieve it with the `Inlines` method.